# Attempt to programmatically re-position UIImageView

Tags: xcode4, uiimageview

**UPDATED QUESTION TO REFLECT ADDITION OF "INIT" IN UIIMAGEVIEW ALLOC*****
I have "imageView" as a variable, declared already in my ".h" class. I am forced in a particular case to programmatically move "imageView" up by about 10 pixels and have experienced no luck. In looking at the current UIImageView ("imageView) position, I determined the X/Y/WIDTH/HEIGHT should be (78,214,170,120). Below is the code I am working with, which works but displays no UIImageView/UIImage:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img2String]]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(78,214,170,120);     
imageView.image = image;
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should initialize your image view first

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

like above.

Comment: Thank you! However, the image still is not appearing. It is NOT null, as I confirmed it in fact loads. But it is not visible...

Answer (score 0):

The question was edited by @greg23af , so I make some change.

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img2String];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(78,214,170,120);
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
imageView.image = image;
```

1. Separate the one line code of loading image into three or four lines
   to let debug easily.
2. Set the UIImageView's background color to see if it is in the
   visible part. Be sure that it is added on the self.view or something
   else.

You forget to init it before.

Comment: Thank you! However, the image still is not appearing. It is NOT null, as I confirmed it in fact loads. But it is not visible...

Comment: @greg23af I think you can load the image step by step to debug. That is, separate the one line into three or four lines to see each result.

Comment: Is your imageView visible ? @greg23af

Comment: Update: removing the "imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];" completely makes the image appear! Only issue now is that despite changing the values, the UIImageView position won't change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26069/discussion-between-greg23af-and-jason-lee)